# Ошибка: import javax cannot be resolved

Tags: java, swing, eclipse, импорт

Указал в коде

```
import javax.swing.*;
```

Подсветило javax с сообщением import "javax cannot be resolved"
Версия JDK - 14.0.1

Может надо как-то отдельно ее ставить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project посмотрите может помочь

Comment: поставь 8ую версию